# MSChart About chart1 BeginInit and EndInit is it needed to Use them always?

Tags: mschart

At MSChart when using at chart1 and do things now i use chart1.BeginInit do stuff and use chart1.EndInit, I don't know if this is needed and i even don't have a clue what is correct usage of chart1.Begin and End Init in general

Can Anybody "clarify"/ **tell about When to use Or simply never use BeginInit and EndInit routines of chart1** would be helpfull ?

Thanks

Comment: Its not needed I have never used it.

Answer (score 0):

BeginInit and EndInit are related to the ISupportInitialize Interface, and you can read about this at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize.aspx

Also do an all file find for BeginInit for the MSChart example project.

It's mostly for setting many properties that are dependent on each other or prevent a potential over-load of paint messages or internal logic confusion from many property settings.  Think of it like a better way of setting all control Visible properties to false, making adjustments, and then setting control Visible = true.

If you don't have a problem to solve by implementing these methods, I would not use it.  Else model your use from the mschart example project.